# Escape Nullable Object Must Have Value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have code that looks like this:

```
 Using dbContext as IRFEntities = New IRFEntities
 Dim getProspect = (From p in dbContext.IRF_Prospects _
                     where p.url = prospect_url _
                     Select p).FirstOrDefault
 If getProspect.user_id Is Nothing Then
                    ' Prepopulate the form with their information.
                    ' These must have a value, so we need to make sure that no column is null in the database.
                    ddlProgram.SelectedValue = getProspect.program
                    txtFirst.Text = getProspect.first_name
                    txtLast.Text = getProspect.last_name
                    txtAddress.Text = getProspect.address
                    txtCity.Text = getProspect.city
                    ddlState.SelectedValue = getProspect.state
                    txtZip.Text = getProspect.zip
                    txtPhone.Text = getProspect.phone
                    txtEmail.Text = getProspect.email_address
                    txtYearEnrolling.Text = getProspect.enrolling_in
                Else
                    ' Redirect them to login.
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                End If
   End Using
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>
> HResult=-2146233079
>
> Message=Nullable object must have a value.

On the following line of code:

```
txtYearEnrolling.Text = getProspect.enrolling_in
```

I know why I am getting the error - the value is null in the database. What I'd like to do is pull the value if it exists, but if it doesn't, I'd like it to either take a default value or just leave the field blank. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure since you didn't define what `getProspect.enrolling_in` is.  What is `getProspect`, and what is the type of `enrolling_in`?  What is the value of that property/field at the time when it throws the exception?

Comment: I've added additional code to the original question to hopefully make things clearer. Essentially, getProspect is the result of a query against IRF_Prospects. If there is a matching row, then the code redirects to the login page (since the user already has an account), if there is not it prepopulates a form with the info. we have in the db on them. The issue is that enrolling_in (or any other field) may not have data in it - it may be null.

Comment: If enrolling_in is a nullable data type (as it seems), you can call GetValueOrDefault() and specify a default value.  Or use the null coalescing operator (??)